# comment in bash script processed by slurm

Tags: bash, comments, hpc, slurm

I am using `slurm` on a cluster to run jobs and submit a script that looks like below with `sbatch`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

#SBATCH -o slurm.sh.out
#SBATCH -p defq
#SBATCH --mail-type=ALL
#SBATCH --mail-user=my.email@something.com

echo "hello"
```

Can I somehow comment out a `#SBATCH` line, e.g. the `#SBATCH --mail-user=my.email@something.com` in this script? Since the `slurm` instructions are bash comments themselves I would not know how to achieve this.

Comment: I\`m quite sure that `sbatch` treats `#SBATCH` as a single token, so inserting a space between `#` and `SBATCH` can help.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

just add another `#` at the beginning.

`##SBATCH --mail-user...`

This will not be processed by Slurm

Comment: Can we do `#SBATCH --option=value # description of the option`?

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few options for comments in slurm scripts:

- double octothorp leading characters comments out the entire line, e.g.: `##SBATCH -t 00:00:01`
- trailing octothorp comment at end of the line, e.g.: `#SBATCH -t 00:00:01 # test`
- special `--comment=<string>` option, e.g.: `#SBATCH --comment "test"`

See the [slurm page on sbatch](https://slurm.schedmd.com/sbatch.html) for more details.